# mongodb recovery removed records

Tags: mongodb, collections, replication, recover

I have a two-member replica set, I accidentally removed all documents in an collection, I am not sure how I did this, but it's gone. 
Is it possible to get all the data back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a [backup](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Backups) (always recommended for just this type of thing), or one of the replicas is using [slavedelay](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#replica-set-delayed-members), then I am afraid the removal of the records is final.  You might have been able to force a shutdown in time to save the data on-disk if you killed the process before the next fsync to disk (similarly if you broke replication before the removal was replicated), but even then it would be tricky.

Comment: I have a time machine backup for mac, but I cannt simply copy it as some of the collections are out of date. Is it possible to only recovery one collection? Under the db directory, there are db-0, db-1, db-2, and db-ns files. Thanks

Comment: Yes - if you can access the data files or copy them out somewhere elsem then you can use mongodump to query the files directly using --dbpath - there is no need to have a mongod process running to do so.  Then just follow the instructions here to dump out a specific collection: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-Example%3ADumpingaSingleCollection

Comment: You can also take the route of copying out the old files, starting a separate standalone mongod (different port, no replSet argument) process and point it at the old data as its dbpath.  Then you can query or dump the collection out from that standalone mongod

Comment: Works. Thanks. Also I am surprised that mongo eats 2GB storage but my data are only about 15MB

Comment: That's usually the journal and the oplog on top of the data - you can start with --smallfiles option if you only plan on having a small data set to help.  The oplog can be resized also to a smaller size (but it requires that it be removed and recreated).